# Алгоритм равномерного распределения заданий между исполнителями

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Есть х задач, разбитых по у секциям. Задача - как можно более равномерно распределить задачи между z исполнителями, при этом не разделяя секцию на нескольких исполнителей.
Если количество секций <= исполнителям, секции распределяются рандомно (некоторые исполнители могут остаться без секций).
Если секций > исполнителей, уже сложнее.
Мое предложение таково:

1. Найти среднее арифметическое кол-во задач на секцию.
2. Секции, задач в которых больше среднего, распределить и удалить из массива секций.
3. Оставшиеся секции отсортировать.
4. Складывать и назначать наименьшую секцию с наибольшей, пока массив не останется пуст.

Ввиду вероятной высокой сложности алгоритма подозреваю, что есть какой нибудь элементарный алгоритм, ускользающий от меня. Возможно, есть идеи?

Comment: Используйте обычный жадный алгоритм. Отсортируйте секции по критерию, по которому требуется усреднение нагрузки (скажем, время на секцию, если усреднение нужно по количеству, сортировка не требуется). Далее просто назначайте самую затратную из неназначенных секций самому незагруженному на текущий момент исполнителю (если таких несколько - любому). Это не гарантирует оптимума (хотя не исключает), но решение будет близко к нему. Ну а поиск оптимума - это типичная NP. Полный перебор. По сути - задача о рюкзаках.

Comment: @Akina Как же выбирать самую затратную секцию, если не сортировать массив? Через поиск максимума по секции на каждом шаге и поиск минимума по нагруженности соответственно?

Comment: Хотите без сортировки? ну перебирайте... я лично не знаю, как ещё можно найти максимальный/минимальный элемент в несортированном списке/массиве...

Comment: @Akina вы сами сказали, если усреднение нужно по количеству задач в секции, сортировка не требуется. 
а на помощь в поиске min/max мне придут уже готовые функции языка. Хотя под капотом у них, конечно, все тот же перебор

Comment: *вы сами сказали, если усреднение нужно по количеству задач в секции, сортировка не требуется. а на помощь в поиске min/max мне придут уже готовые функции языка.* Вы не перемешивайте сортировку исходного списка задач и сортировку списка исполнителей для поиска наиболее "свободного" - это как бы немножко разные списки.